# Downloading files(.zip, .jar,...) to a folder

Tags: java, file, url, file-io, download

I have been trying many ways of downloading a file from a URL and putting it in a folder.

```
public static void saveFile(String fileName,String fileUrl) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(fileUrl), new File(fileName));
}

boolean success = (new File("File")).mkdirs();
if (!success) {
Status.setText("Failed");
}
    try {
        saveFile("DownloadedFileName", "ADirectDownloadLinkForAFile");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Status.setText("MalformedURLException");
        Logger.getLogger(DownloadFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Status.setText("IOException Error");
        Logger.getLogger(DownloadFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I found this code on the net, am i using it correctly?

If i did:
    saveFile("FolderName", "ADirectDownloadLinkForAFile")

I would get `IOException` error

What I want my code to do is:

1. Create folder
2. Download file
3. Downloaded file to go to the just created folder

I'm a newbie here sorry. Please help

Comment: How does this relate to Apache HTTP server? Do you mean Apache Tomcat? And why you say you're a newbie - you're here for 2 months...

Comment: I don't know. *Are* you using it correctly ? Do you get any errors ?

Comment: "I found this code on the net, am i using it correctly?" Probably not if you have to ask that. You should try to understand any code you read on the web instead of just using it blindly. We have no idea what `Status` or `VanillaChoose` are or how `saveFile()` is implemented or what the parameters mean. Or how this code is failing for you.

Comment: @home i rarely do programming, and rarely come online here. @I have tried to understand what i copied from the web does. B

Comment: What is the purpose of all this?  What feature does it provide the end user?

Comment: Start by reading the message of the exception. It tells you what's wrong. My guess is: ADirectDownloadLinkForAFile is not a valid URL. A URL is what you see in your browser address bar. Assuming you want to download from the web, it starts with `http://`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways in java to download a file from the internet.
The easiest one is to use a buffer and a stream:

```
File theDir = new File("new folder");

  // if the directory does not exist, create it
  if (!theDir.exists())
  {
    System.out.println("creating directory: " + directoryName);
    boolean result = theDir.mkdir();  
    if(result){    
       System.out.println("DIR created");  
     }

  }
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(theDir.getAbsolutePath() +"filename"));
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("URLtoYourFIle").openStream());
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
int count;
        while((count = in.read(data,0,1024)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(data, 0, count);
        }
```

Just the basic concept. Dont forget the close the streams ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `File.mkdirs()` statement appears to be creating a folder called `Files`, but the `saveFile()` method doesn't appear to be using this, and simply saving the file in the current directory.